# Calculate and plot the theoretical normal distribution N(2, 1) in the interval of [-1, 5]

Tags: python, numpy, probability, normal-distribution, probability-density

I've been giving the task to calculate and plot the normal distribution N(2, 1) in the interval of [-1, 5]

Here's what I've tried:

```
vec = np.random.norm(2, 1, 7);
ND = stats.norm(2, 1).pdf(vec)
x = np.arange(1, 6, 1)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, 'r')
plt.hist(ND)
plt.show()
```

As you may have figured out this does not give me the result I'm looking for.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Please note that I am a student that has only recently started coding in Python.

I have been asked to generate random numbers with np.random.normal ranging from -1 to 5. However I have yet to understand how I can do that considering the the interval begins at -1.

Secondly I have been asked to use the function norm.pdf from scipy.stats but I do not understand the documentation on this function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)

Finally I have to plot the results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: @wwii Well do you mind suggesting a forum that would help me out on this issue?

Comment: When trying to use a new tool the manual is a good place to start. Invest some time with the documentation, experimenting along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify an N(2,1) distribution is to say that you want a normal distribution with mean 2 and variance (or standard deviation) 1. In scipy terms, mean is equivalent to location, and standard deviation to scale.

To make a plot of the pdf using matplotlib you chooose sufficient points on the interval [-1, 5] to make a visually smooth graph. This is the purpose of `linspace`. For each of these points you calculate its pdf using `norm.pdf`.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 5, 100, endpoint=True)
pdf = [norm.pdf(_, loc=2, scale=1) for _ in x]

plt.plot(x, pdf, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Here I create a sample of size 10. I know that `norm.rvs` will produce deviates over the entire real line; therefore, to obtain deviates for the desired interval I simply ignore the ones outside that interval. Each invocation of `norm.rvs' produces a numpy 'array' of length one. To obtain a nice result I select just the first item in that array and append it to the overall sample (if it's within the desired interval).

```
sample_size = 10
sample = []
while len(sample)<sample_size:
    while True:
        deviate = norm.rvs(loc=2, scale=1, size=1)[0]
        if -1<=deviate<=5:
            break
    sample.append(deviate)
print (sample)
```